# why do I got Uncaught TypeError: response.text is not a function" error when try to assignt body received as text to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, select, drop-down-menu

I got a mock server who responds with a body text like this: "2020-05-02 2020-05-05 2020-05-07 2020-05-15 2020-05-16" then I try to insert each o these elements in an javascript array using this func:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let response = fetch("http://127.0.0.1:35980/returnBalancesDates")
        let value =  response.text();
        var choices =  value.split(' ');
        console.log(choices)
        var x = document.createElement("SELECT");
        x.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
        x.setAttribute("name", "oldbaldate");
        document.body.appendChild(x);

        for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i = i + 1) {
            var z = document.createElement("option");
            z.setAttribute("value", choices[i]);
            var t = document.createTextNode(choices[i]);
            z.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(z);
        }
        $(x).appendTo('#selectOldBalance');
    });
</script>
```

In browser console I see this error and my select element is not created in html page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: response.text is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):75)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the script that worked for me:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:35980/returnBalancesDates')
            .then(dataWrappedByPromise => dataWrappedByPromise.text())
            .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
        var choices =  data.split(' ');
        console.log(choices);
        var x = document.createElement("SELECT");
        x.setAttribute("id", "mySelect");
        x.setAttribute("name", "oldbaldate");
        document.body.appendChild(x);

        for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i = i + 1) {
            var z = document.createElement("option");
            z.setAttribute("value", choices[i]);
            var t = document.createTextNode(choices[i]);
            z.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(z);
        }
        $(x).appendTo('#selectOldBalance');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Fetch is async, so when you call `response.text()` you actually dont have the response yet. Either use `response = await fetch` or callbacks.